# настройка ssh для подключения к удаленному хосту.

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-key

Не получается использовать ssh-key для подключения без ввода пароля.

вот что я делаю:

1. генерировал ключ `ssh-keygen -t rsa`
2. `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`
3. `ssh-add .ssh/id_rsa`
4. скопировал `.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, открыл через putty и сохранил приватный и публичный ключ.
5. подкорректировал `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` и перезагрузил `sshd`

> Using username "MyUser".
>
> Server refused our key

попробовал скопировать authorized_keys в `/etc/ssh/authorized_keys`  и в `root`, так как сервис от рука запускается. проблему не решает.

Подскажите что я делаю не так и как мне выполнить поставленную задачу?

Comment: выкиньте пункты про putty, «сохранение» непонятно чего непонятно куда, перезапуск sshd и корректировку его конфигурации. `~/.ssh/id_rsa` — это ваш секретный ключ, а `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` — публичный. оба сгенерированы в первом пункте. второй надо копировать в `~/.ssh/` на целевой машине.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте пошагово и, если будут сложности, скажите, на каком шаге возникает проблема.

Действия на локальном компьютере:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 1024 -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Копируем ключи на удаленный компьютер, к которому будем подключаться по ключам:

```
$ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@ip.ad.re.ss
```

или

```
 $ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@ip.ad.re.ss "cat - >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Comment: я понял в чем ошибка была. я не указывал `user@ip.ad.re.ss`. спасибо