# отправка публичного ключа на ssh сервер для подлкючения без пароля

Tags: bash, ssh, скрипт

Пишу скрипт на bash для копирования файла на сервер (прицип не важен). Для подключения скрипта к серверу без пароля сделал все по иструкции: сгенирировал ключи, скинул публичный на сервер, изменил в файле /etc/ssh/sshd_config на

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeyFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

но все равно при подключении требует пароль. Хз что не так сделал. Знает кто решение этой тривиальной задачи?

UPD: мб это важно, но у меня стоит ubuntu, а ещё на сервере порт изменен (я его тоже указываю при подключении)

Comment: "_скинул публичный на сервер_" - скинули куда ? в домашний каталог пользователя под которым подключаетесь в файл .ssh/authorized_keys ? убедились, что правда доступа на каталог .ssh и сам файл разрешают доступ только самому пользователю ? Запустите подключение с ключем -v и изучите что он там пишет, там должно быть видно попытки послать ключ и ответы от сервера

Comment: конечно же в .ssh/authorized_keys. Права: owner create & delete files.
в баг репорте из интересного только     debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for * и debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1,  а ещё debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa хотя у меня id_rsa

Comment: попробуйте явно сделать dsa ключ (`ssh-keygen -t dsa`) может ваш ssh с какой то из сторон не хочет работать с rsa

Comment: замечательно, теперь вооще не подключается к серверу даже напрямую пишет

    /etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 58: Bad configuration option: authorizedkeysfile
    /etc/ssh/ssh_config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options, есть способ откатить все и заного сделать?

Comment: Ну собственно поправить обратно файл или очистить его. вы же консоль активную к серверу оставили, которая еще не дисконнектилась ? правда для начала надо разобраться с какой из сторон проблемы в конфиге. если что, можно попробовать подключится под другим пользователем и сделать `su -` уже локально, что бы стать нужным

Comment: дубликат? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/651796/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-ssh-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83

Comment: удалил все что можно, пересоздал опять. В /etc/ssh/ только 2 файла  moduli  и .sshd_config.swp. Хотя я как понял мне нужен ssh_config которого нет (.sshd_config.swp вообще по-моему побайтово прописан)

Comment: @Senior Pomidor не дубилкат, у него была легко решаемая ошибка, а у меня не робит по странной пречине

Comment: Вы описываете конфиг сервера как я понял. На клиенте запустите ssh -v покажет, что происходит. Для копирования ключа используйте ssh-copy-id и пропишите в ~/.ssh/config использование ключа. Проверте pam модуль на сервере.